# SQL Server : GPS distance returning invalid floating point

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, gps

I have a table in a SQL Server database that contains columns:

```
ID, Latitude, Longitude
```

I want to calculate the distance between each point and take all that are less, but when I apply the `WHERE distance < 10` I'm getting an error

> An invalid floating point operation occurred

I'm not sure what im doing wrong, because it's working perfectly without the `WHERE` clause.

My code:

```
SELECT 
    [t5].Name as Hotel1, [t6].Name as Hotel2, Distance
FROM
    (SELECT 
         [t2].ID as GPS1, [T1].ID as GPS2,
         (ACOS(Cos(PI()*[t1].Latitude/180.0) * Cos(PI() * [t1].Longitude/180.0) * Cos(PI()*[t2].Latitude/180.0) * Cos(PI() * [t2].Longitude/180.0) + Cos(PI()*[t1].Latitude/180.0) * Sin(PI() * [t1].Longitude/180.0) * Cos(PI()*[t2].Latitude/180.0) * Sin(PI() *[t2].Longitude/180.0) + Sin(PI()*[t1].Latitude/180.0) * Sin(PI() * [t2].[Latitude]/180.0)) * 6371) AS Distance
     FROM 
         GPSLocations [t1]
     JOIN 
         GPSLocations [t2] ON [t1].ID <> [t2].ID) [t4]
JOIN 
    Hotels [t5] ON [t5].FK_GPSLocationID = GPS1
JOIN 
    Hotels [t6] ON [t6].FK_GPSLocationID = GPS2
WHERE 
    distance < 10
```

Sample data:

GPSLocations table looks like this

```
Latitude    Longitude       ID
39,7531224  -105,0001446    847
55,10309    12,31064        581
55,10317    12,37527        684
55,10382    9,35923         740
55,1097     12,50471        636
55,11163    10,77026        358
55,11366    11,74766        668
```

Hotel table looks like this:

```
ID  Name                    FK_GPSLocationID
64  Hotel Findus            59
65  Best Western CPH        60
66  Comwell Middelfart      61
67  Hotel Middelfart        62
68  Master demo 1           63
69  Sky hotel 1             64
70  Rene bigstart hotel 3   65
```

This is just sample data and there for the foreign keys do not match.

All the GPS locations can be downloaded here: http://noxiaz.dk/GPSLocations.txt

The joins with the table `Hotels` makes no difference on the error im getting

Comment: Could you show us some sample data?

Comment: Hi, i have now added sample data - You are as well able to download the whole list of GPSlocations that exist in the database